# JQuery UI- Dialog: How to make an callback in the Dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I facing a problem on the JQuery Dialog which wrote in such to ask user to enter comment but the function not work properly due to asyn AJAX.

Here is the sample code

HTML

```
    <header>
    <nav>
        <input type="button" id="to-execute" value="Execute"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="data1" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" id="data2" value="2" />
    </nav>
</header>


<div id="add-comment" style="display:none;">
    <b>Please enter comment:</b>
    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#to-execute").live("click", function() {
        if (calUtils.addCalculation() && calUtils.commentAdd()) {
            return calUtils.endResult();
        }
        alert("I not enter the function at all");
    });
});


var calUtils = {
    addCalculation: function() {
        var sum = parseInt($("#data1").val()) + parseInt($("#data2").val());
        if (sum > 0) {
            alert("More than Zero. Sum =" + sum);
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Less than Zero. Sum =" + sum);
            return false;
        }
    },
    commentAdd: function() {
        // Dialog
        $("#add-comment").dialog({
            title: "Comment",
            modal: false,
            width: "500",
            resizable: false,
            position: "center",
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                },
                "Confirm": function() {
                    var comment = $("#add-comment textarea").val();
                    if (!comment && comment != null) {
                        alert("Please enter Comment!");
                        return false;
                    }
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }).dialog("open");

    },
    endResult: function() {
        alert("Thanks you");
    }
}
```

---

When clicked an Execute button, the function not wait for calUtils.commentAdd() to finish executed before proceed to the next line. This will caused calUtils.endResult() never execute forever.

Can someone intelligently tell me what wrong with my code? 
How can I code in such the program will execute calUtils.endResult() when both of the (calUtils.addCalculation() && calUtils.commentAdd()) == TRUE?

You can try the code here
http://jsfiddle.net/fsloke/4qdsx/1/

Thanks
-fsloke

Answer (score 0):

Your function "calUtils.commentAdd()" will always return undefined for current statement, which means calUtils.addCalculation() && calUtils.commentAdd() will always false. I think that's why your "calUtils.endResult()" never work.

Comment: Due to the ajax call caused it undefined, anyway how to make this work?